# How to find a realisable starting point with the Simplex algorithm?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let be the following linear program:

\begin{equation*}
     \begin{cases}
        \max f(x_1,x_2) =3x_1+2x_2\\
        5x_1 + 2x_2 \ge 8\\
        x_1 - x_2 \le 1\\
        x_1 + x_2 \le 3\\
        x_1,x_2\ge 0
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

[image]

I know how to graphically guess where a starting point is but how to find it with the Simplex algorithm?

Here I graphically guess that we would strat from the bottom or the left, but it's only a guess as fas as we are under a $\max$ condition.

After having put in place the begining of the Simplex algorithm, I have:

$$
\begin{array}{llllll}
x_3= 8& -5X_1 &-2X_2 & & &\\
x_4= 1& - X_1& +X_2& &\\
x_5= 3& -X_1 & -X_2 &  & &\\ 
\hline
z= & 3X_1 & + 2X_2
\end{array}
$$

but how to find the starting point from here? I only know that the variable about to come is $X_1$ because it has the greatest coefficient...

Comment: take a look at any linear programming course or at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Finding_an_initial_canonical_tableau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve another linear problem before hand in other to find a feasible solution:
$$
\mbox{Minimize }\;Z= t
$$
subject to
$$
5x_1+2x_2+t\ge 8\\
x_1-x_2\le 1\\
x_1+x_2\le 3\\
x_1,x_2,t\ge 0
$$
The optimal solution of this problem will give you a tuple $(x_1,x_2,t)=(x_1^*,x_2^*,0)$ which is a valid starting point. If you get an optimal solution with $t>0$, the initial problem is not feasible.

Comment: Okay, I will try and let you know, thank you!